# Mytop is not showing queries?

Tags: mysql

I have this issue. Mytop is not showing queries.
I'm using ubuntu.

I followed these steps:

- I installed mytop
- I connected to my database
- I am inserting queries from function and from phpmyadmin

[image]

Comment: @ErgestBasha `show processlist` does not show the queries.

Comment: @ErgestBasha `show processlist` is not showing any queries even if I try a slow query.